# Docker daemon keeps shutting down

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fedora

I am trying to work with docker: build, tag, and deploy images but the daemon keeps shutting down. The workaround is to run `sudo systemctl restart docker` again and again to do something.

I read few answers pertaining to docker containers but I could not find any solution to docker daemon.

The error that I get from time to time:

```
➜  opendatahub-operator git:(master) ✗ sudo docker build --no-cache . 
ERRO[0009] failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: connection refused 
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I tried updating the system (`sudo dnf update`) and there were long pending changes but it had no effect on docker's behavior.

Comment: Try to execute this command: docker-machine start default; docker-machine regenerate-certs default; eval "$(docker-machine env default)"

Comment: What will it do and why should I run it?